# mark value of a column if present in another table sql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

A:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

B:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

I need to introduce a column that marks if ID in A is present in B

| ID | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Y |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | Y |
| 4 | N |

is there any way to do this without adding a flag column to B and coalescing with join?

```
coalesce(B.flag,'N') as flag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and a CASE WHEN clause:

```
select
  a.id,
  case when b.id is not null then 'Y' else 'N' as flag
from
  a left join b on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if something *exists()*...

```
select Id, 
  case when exists (select 0 from TableB b where b.Id = a.Id)
    then 'Y' else 'N'
  end as Flag
from TableA a;
```